# When does the variable expansion/substitution takes place in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

When do variables in pom.xml get replaced, in which phase/goal etc?
How does the command line flag `-D` change the behaviour, when and how does it overwrite the default values of `<properties>` in pom.xml?

I tried searching this in maven official website https://maven.apache.org/ but could not find anything useful, maybe I am not searching with correct keywords.

I am trying to use the `gmaven-plugin version:1.5` to overwrite certain properties:

```
<phase>initialize</phase>
    <goals>
       <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
..
..
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
// Docker registry requires names to be lower case

project.properties["upload.repo"] = StringUtils.lowerCase(project.properties["upload.repo"])
project.properties["upload.name"] = StringUtils.lowerCase(project.properties["upload.name"])
..
..
```

The project properties are used by another plugin as

```
<properties>
..
..
    <upload.repo>myrepo</upload.repo>
    <upload.name>myName</upload.name>
..
..
</properties>
..
..
<uploadTarget>my.internal.host/${upload.repo}/${upload.name}</uploadTarget>
```

When I run the package phase it always end up with the `uploadTarget` value being `my.internal.host/myrepo/myName` whereas I expect it to be `my.internal.host/myrepo/myname` (notice lowercase `myname`)

Comment: As far as I know, the properties are resolved before any phase begins. `-D` replaces parameters from the POM.

Comment: Thanks @JFMeier any doc that you can refer?